# How can i install html theme in my laravel framework

Tags: php, html, laravel

i purchased a themeforest static html template but I have no idea how to install it. can i install this template to my web site that uses the laravel framework?

Comment: have you got an admin backend in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use html theme in Laravel framework . You just copy all the html files in Laravel.Under "rescources/views" and rename all html files with .blade.html extension like index.blade.html and copy all the css files in public/css and change link of css files in html head tag like

Then make routes for accessing the views rather from the controller or from the route/web.php file

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is,

1. Copy all HTML files, and paste into **view** folder.
2. Change all files extensions from .html to .blade.php (eg. `about.html` to `about.blade.php`).
3. Remove the '.html' from all anchors href, so `<a href='about.html'>` will be  `<a href='about'>` and so on.
4. Copy all other files/folder(js folder, css folder, image folder etc) from the root folder to public folder.
5. Create route for your static pages.
   You can create a route for each page or you can create a single common route for all pages, like this..

   ```
    Route::get('{page_name}', function($page_name)
    {
        //
        return View::make('frontend/'.$page_name);
    });
   ```

You can go through the official website: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade